# How do functions defined in my firebug console accept default parameters?

Tags: javascript

#### I didn't think this was supposed to work in javascript:

```
  > var f = function(x, y=1) {return [x,y]}
  > f
  function(x, y=1)

  > f()
  [undefined, 1]

  > f(1)
  [1, 1]

  > f(1,2)
  [1, 2]
```

#### But:

- It works in my firebug console
- I can't find any documentation for default parameters in the method signature in javascript
- It breaks jslint
- It breaks my v8 compiler

#### What's going on?

Comment: Sounds like a Firefox extension, I get an error when I try it in the Chrome console.

Comment: Works in Firefox 30.0 without Firebug installed.

Comment: It's an ECMAScript 6 proposed feature. But currently nothing but FF implements it.

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#default_function_params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to this feature (currently specific to Firefox), default parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters

> Allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.
>   Warning: For Gecko 15 and upper versions.

Compatibility, from MDN:

```
Browser compatibility
Feature         |Chrome         |Firefox (Gecko)    |Internet Explorer  |Opera          |Safari (WebKit)
Basic support   |Not supported  |15 (15)            |Not supported      |Not supported  |Not supported
```

Which would explain why it's only available in FireBug.

Default parameters are in the ECMAScript 6 draft, so we may see them in the future. Compatibility can be found here: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#default_function_params
(Thanks @jonathanlonowski for the link!)